# Android: Hide ActionBar, keep Tabs

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

To keep this simple: I have tabs in my actionbar, but the action bar take up too much space. I want that extra space. I need a way to hide the action bar, yet keep my tabs. Is there anyway to do this? Or is there a way I can get the tabs built into the action bar like it is in landscape mode? Thanks!

Comment: From what I understand the tabs and ActionBar are one, and the system will combine/split them up as it sees fit.

Comment: @Whymarrh No, you *can* have a tabs-only Activity (see my answer) :) Best example would be the contscts app.

Comment: @Ahmad very cool. Did not know it was possible.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can have an empty Actionbar, then the tabs will occupy the space:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);              
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Technically, the "tabs will occupy the space" only when they display as tabs. Action bar tabs will magically change into a drop-down list (the same as seen in list navigation) depending upon screen size and orientation, at which point the action bar will be visible to host that drop-down list. If you really want tabs all the time, and no action bar, use `ViewPager` and an appropriate indicator (e.g., `PagerTabStrip`) and hide the action bar entirely.

Comment: how to achieve it when the theme is strictly "NoActionBar" every where?

Comment: Also in my case i have a fragment in which i need to show swipe tabs. As you know fragment can't host an `ActionBar` any suggestion?

Answer (score 13):

Try the below code:

```
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Also remove the below in code which is added default when project is created:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the second part about the onCreateOptionsMenu. I was wondering why I still had the white bar above my tabs.

Comment: @Marty Can you please paste a snapshot of the screen.

Comment: @Ranjuth: Maybe I wasn't clear, I just wanted to thank you because your comment finally solved my problem. I had the parts where I change the actionBar but I didn't remove the onCreateOptionsMenu which caused the white bar (because title and icon are blank but apparently  it still needs to display something. Anyway here are the [screenshots](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=huhapz&s=8).

Comment: Welcome. Then please mark the question answered. :)

Comment: I can't... didn't ask it in the first place or I would have already :(

Comment: Can anyone please help ?
The code at "Try the below code:" works great but the action-bar still shows it self for half a second when the app starts and than disappears, the code at onCreateOptionsMenu just creates a dark bar with 1 over-flow button,..
I copied-pasted onCreateOptionsMenu to the Activity class.

Comment: Try adding below in style file, set the theme in manifest as AppTheme, but for this to work your minsdkversion should be 14.

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>`

Comment: Thanks Ranjith, but sadly I have a critical code that will only work with minsdkversion == 16 :(
Is there any other solution ?

Comment: Ya then this will work for you. The code I mentioned above requires minimum 14 since your code requires 16 which is greater it will work.

Answer (score 3):

This did the trick for me

```
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

I also commented the line

```
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahmad's answer is correct but it requires API 11. For supporting lower APIs, use this code -

```
setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
```

To enable it, use -

```
setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)
```

Comment: Is it possible to animate this ?

Comment: Try checking this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949879/hiding-actionbar-timed-and-animating-views/21949939#21949939