# Hiding ActionBar (Timed) and Animating Views

Tags: java, android, animation, android-actionbar, fragment

Here is basically what I want to happen:

**In prose:**

Hide `ActionBar`. Then do some animation(s). Wait a little bit. Show `ActionBar` again.

**In basic code:**

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();

TextView someTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.some_textview);
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
int duration = 1000;
a.setDuration(duration);
someTextView.startAnimation(a);

wait(duration);

actionBar.show();
```

**In actuality:**

Of course, the way the code is written, it doesn't work how I want. I've tried several solutions, including: (1) using `Thread.sleep`, (2) creating new `Runnables`, (3) creating two instances of `ActionBar` (one for hiding and one for showing), and maybe even a few more methods that I don't recall anymore.

Basically, so far, what has happened as a result has been either (1) the `ActionBar` is shown the entire time, (2) or the whole program waits, the `ActionBar` is shown, then the animation plays, or (3) some version of the same out-of-order run.

**So I guess my question is:**

How do I hide the `ActionBar`, do an animation or two, then show it again? (FYI: I'm running this in a class that extends a `Fragment`, not an `Activity`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html). At the end of the `Animation`, show `ActionBar` again.

```
    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // You can hide ActionBar here
            getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // getActivity().getActionBar().show();
            // and according to you, use Handler
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getActivity().getActionBar().show();
                }
            }, 3 * 1000);
        }
    });
    someTextView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: Thank you. That looks really good. But how do I make it wait some amount of time before `getActionBar().show()` (i.e., not display the `ActionBar` immediately)?

Comment: Yes, let's say, for example: after animation finishes, wait 3 seconds, show `ActionBar`.